# Настройка postback

Tags: php

Смешной вопрос: люди помогите разобраться с *postback*.

1. *Postback* - что это такое;
2. Какие сервисы/механизмы существуют.

Comment: мне кажется, или вопрос очень общий?

Comment: Да не очень, непонимаю вообще что это.

Comment: Вообщем если коротко, постбек предназначен для получения [конверсии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%B2_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5))

Comment: Суть в том, что при отправки формы формируется postback URL с основными параметрами для конверсии сайта.

Comment: http://barsag.com/2013/01/03/chto-takoe-postback/